# Android: Starting a new Broadcast from within an BOOT_COMPLETED receiver

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, broadcast

i have a BOOT_COMPLETED receiver which is successfully getting called after the phones boot.
However, i am trying to start a new Broadcast Intent in the Boot-Receiver's onReceive method, but it is not working:

```
public class BootCompletedReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {


@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    //ObservableObject.getInstance().updateValue(intent);

    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent dayCheckIntent = new Intent(context, DayCheckReceiver.class);


    PendingIntent dayCheckAlarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 2000000000, dayCheckIntent, 0);

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 6);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 1);
    if (calendar.before(Calendar.getInstance()) || calendar.equals(Calendar.getInstance())) {
        calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
    }

    alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), dayCheckAlarmIntent);

}
}
```

Also i wonder, if it is possible, to call an ObservableObject's updateValue() in the Boot-Broadcast, which then calls a MainActivity method, without the App running?

**EDIT:**

I found out, it works if i dont destroy the app over the Task Manager before rebooting. But if i empty the Task Manager, it doesnt work (i think onreceive i still called tho, since i tested it with a notification. it just seems to not execute the new alarm)

Comment: did you add `DayCheckReceiver.class` in manifest?

Comment: Yup. I have the same Code Snippet in the Main Activity and DayCheckReceiver is working when i set it up from there.

Comment: how are you checking that code is not working. You are setting alarm for `6:01 AM`. Right?

Comment: Yea i set it to 6:01 because that was the time when i tested it.